# Why Smart Card answers 6982 to EXTERNAL AUTHENTICATE while all calculations are correct?

Tags: python, authentication, smartcard, apdu, globalplatform

I am trying to establish a secure channel `SCP02` with a smart card using python. My smartcard is connected to the terminal using a serial port and I use `pySerial` to send APDUs.

I send commands `SELECT ISD`, `INITIALIZE UPDATE` correctly, and next I try to do `EXTERNAL AUTHENTICATE` as the python code below:

```
import serial
from serial.serialutil import EIGHTBITS, PARITY_NONE, STOPBITS_ONE, XON
import exchangeApdu
import numpy as np
from Crypto.Cipher import DES, DES3

CARD_KEY = [0x40, 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x45, 0x46, 0x47, 0x48, 0x49, 0x4A, 0x4B, 0x4C, 0x4D, 0x4E, 0x4F]
ZERO_IV_8 = [0X00, 0X00, 0x00, 0x00, 0X00, 0X00, 0x00, 0x00]

serialObj = serial.Serial(  port = 'COM3', \
                            baudrate = 115200, \
                            parity = PARITY_NONE, \
                            bytesize = EIGHTBITS, \
                            stopbits = STOPBITS_ONE, \
                            timeout = 0.1, \
                            xonxoff = True, \
                            rtscts = True, \
                            inter_byte_timeout = None, \
                            dsrdtr = True   )
if(serialObj.is_open):
    serialObj.close()
serialObj.open()

# Select ISD
select_apdu = [0x00, 0xA4, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00]
response = exchangeApdu.exchange(serialObj, select_apdu)
print('Select ISD: ' + response.hex())

# Initialize Update
host_challenge = np.random.bytes(8)
initialize_update_apdu = [0x80, 0x50, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08] + list(host_challenge)
response = exchangeApdu.exchange(serialObj, initialize_update_apdu)
print('Initialize Update: ' + response.hex())

key_derivation_data = list(response[:10])
key_information = list(response[10:12])
sequence_counter = list(response[12:14])
card_challenge = list(response[14:20])
card_cryptogram = list(response[20:28])

derivation_data = [0X01, 0X82] + sequence_counter + \
    [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]
encryptor = DES3.new(bytes(CARD_KEY), DES3.MODE_CBC, bytes(ZERO_IV_8))
S_ENC = encryptor.encrypt(bytes(derivation_data))
derivation_data = [0X01, 0X01] + sequence_counter + \
    [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]
encryptor = DES3.new(bytes(CARD_KEY), DES3.MODE_CBC, bytes(ZERO_IV_8))
S_MAC = encryptor.encrypt(bytes(derivation_data))

# External Authenticate
PADDING_DES = [0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]
host_auth_data = sequence_counter + card_challenge + list(host_challenge) + PADDING_DES
card_auth_data = list(host_challenge) + sequence_counter + card_challenge + PADDING_DES
encryptor = DES3.new(bytes(S_ENC), DES3.MODE_CBC, bytes(ZERO_IV_8))
host_cryptogram = list(bytes((encryptor.encrypt(bytes(host_auth_data)))[-8:]))
encryptor = DES3.new(bytes(S_ENC), DES3.MODE_CBC, bytes(ZERO_IV_8))
card_cryptogram = list(bytes((encryptor.encrypt(bytes(card_auth_data)))[-8:]))

external_auth_apdu = [0x84, 0x82, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10] + list(host_cryptogram)
external_auth_apdu_padded = external_auth_apdu + [0x80, 0x00, 0x00]
cipher = DES.new(bytes(list(S_MAC[:8])), DES3.MODE_CBC, bytes(ZERO_IV_8))
step1 = cipher.encrypt(bytes(external_auth_apdu_padded))
cipher = DES.new(bytes(list(S_MAC[8:16])), DES3.MODE_ECB)
step2 = cipher.decrypt(step1[-8:])
cipher = DES.new(bytes(list(S_MAC[:8])), DES3.MODE_ECB)
apdu_mac = list(bytes(cipher.encrypt(step2[-8:])))
external_auth_apdu = external_auth_apdu + apdu_mac
response = exchangeApdu.exchange(serialObj, external_auth_apdu)
print('External Authenticate: ' + response.hex())

serialObj.close()
```

The "exchangeApdu" is a class in which I have handled APDUs like 61xx and 6Cxx. This is the output for this code:

```
Select ISD: 6f108408a000000151000000a5049f6501ff9000
Initialize Update: 000081210103b49d856dff02004eecc2acd14944a54f9790521d203b9000
External Authenticate: 6982
```

Smartcard rejects the channel sending back `6982` on the serial port. I have checked whole the procedure uwing online cryptography tools and I am quite sure the cryptographic part is completely doing right.
I have also checked this procedure using a usb smartcard reader and again correctly working and I get `9000`.
Again I checked this on a smartcard simulator, namely JCIDE, and again `9000`.
Thus I'm sure about the procedure correctness.
I have used a serial port monitoring application on Win10 to check the correctness of APDUs on the serial port and there is no error. I think there must be a problem with the smartcard itself but I cannot guess what it is!

Does anyone have any idea where the problem rises?

Comment: On thing you can do to check if crypto is correct is using GlobalplaformPro in debug mode, so you will get not only APDU but also the keys and cryptographic calculations. Based on that, you can include those APDUs as input of your program and validate that everything works as expected.

Comment: @jlanza Thank you for your response. Unfortunately in the INITIALIZE UPDATE step, card generates a random byte array (Card Challenge) which is further used in the procedure of EXTERNAL AUTHENTICATE as shown in the codes above. So, these APDUs are not applicable for other sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the roblem. Byte array is not delivered to the card correctly, hence the error 6982.
This refers to ISO7816 standard which needs bytes sent to the card by a specific delay. I put delays between bytes and now everything is working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the working [Test Vectors](https://github.com/kaoh/globalplatform/blob/master/globalplatform/src/scp02Test.c) from the GlobalPlatform library and test if your executed crypto logic is really working. It could also be that your card is using some key derivation scheme, i.e. the keys you are using cannot be used directly.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have used the same smart card in a USB smart card reader with the same codes as mentioned in the question and it works correctly returning `9000` in response to EXTERNAL AUTHENTICATE. Thus, I think this is may not be the case!!! What's your opinion? Is there any initialization when connecting to a USB smartcard reader taht are forgotten to be done in the customized serial port reader?

Comment: Which channel is used? Usually the basic channel 0 is used, maybe the modem is using a different channel, maybe a logical one which has to be considered when creating the APDUs? I assume you are using some AT commands to talk to the modem?

Comment: I think you are confused with another question! Here the problem is a smartcard reader.

Comment: I was thinking you are using a serial connection and thought of a classical serial modem connection then. See https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Modem-HOWTO-4.html But is seems you are using a special smart card driver hiding these details and you are seeing a standard smart card reader attached to PC/SC?

Comment: It is a microcontroller (STM) connected to USB port of the system and it creates a virtual serial port (COM3 here) which sends and receives APDUs between PC and smartcard. I don't know why the smartcard prevents setting up a secure channel and returns 6982 while same APDUs are working using a standard smartcard reader!!!

Comment: Can you start under Linux "pcscd -a -d -f" to see all PC/SC details? Maybe this is giving you an answer. In addition you can use Wireshark to monitor there USB traffic. This week be low level, but it seems you have a very specific problem.

Comment: pcscd is not going to work because I am not using a standard PC/SC smart card reader and APDU. I'm just sending APDUs as byte arrays on the serial port to the microcontroller and it delivers them to the smartcard. It does great for the first two commands (select ISD and INITIALIZE UPDATE), but fails on EXTERNAL AUTHENTICATE and I have checked and am quite sure about the cryptography details to be true.

Comment: Not sure if the power up behavior and ATR has any behavior on this. Is the ATR the same? Some cars also show different behavior for contactless and contact cards.

Comment: Yes, ATR is the same in both custom and standard readers. Everything looks natural except the EXTERNAL AUTHENTICATE command which the card rejects while it is correctly calculated.

Comment: Can you debug what the STM controller is doing with the APDUs and how they are mapped to TPDUs send to the card? Maybe the STM is doing something transparently, e.g. using a logical channel, auto answering something,etc.

Comment: I checked both microcontroller side and compared with a standard reader. There was no problem at the microcontroller side and all APDUs were the same as sent on serial port. Afterward, I installed a USB port monitor appplication on my PC and found that there are lots of information sent and received between PC and Reader and I don't know what they can be! whether they are configurations or not important!

Comment: This is then the issue. If the current transaction gets injected destroyed by different APDUs the INITIALIZE UPDATE session is destroyed. I know that e.g. under Windows the smart card service tries to detect the card and sends several commands to identify possible applets.